# Pandas df.describe() , is it possible to do it by row without transposing?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas [df.describe()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) is a very useful method to have an overview of your df. However, it describes by columns and I would like to have an overview of the rows instead. Is there any way to make it work "by_row" without transposing the df?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `apply` and pass `axis=1` to call `describe` row-wise:

```
In [274]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,5))
df

Out[274]:
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.651863  0.738034 -0.477668 -0.561699  0.047500
1 -1.565093 -0.671551  0.537272 -0.956520  0.301156
2 -0.951549  2.177592  0.059961 -1.631530 -0.620173
3  0.277796  0.169365  1.657189  0.713522  1.649386

In [276]:
df.apply(pd.DataFrame.describe, axis=1)

Out[276]:
   count      mean       std       min       25%       50%       75%       max
0      5  0.079606  0.609069 -0.561699 -0.477668  0.047500  0.651863  0.738034
1      5 -0.470947  0.878326 -1.565093 -0.956520 -0.671551  0.301156  0.537272
2      5 -0.193140  1.458676 -1.631530 -0.951549 -0.620173  0.059961  2.177592
3      5  0.893451  0.722917  0.169365  0.277796  0.713522  1.649386  1.657189
```

Answer (score 6):

EdChum answer did not work for me, because with the apply command all the rows are Series; by using`pd.Series.describe` it worked

```
df.apply(pd.Series.describe, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the above solutions didn't work when applying them on a single column.
The following solution using transpose did work for me:

- Multiple columns

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,5))
  df.describe().T
  ```
- Single column

  ```
  df[[0]].describe().T
  ```

Resulting in:

```
   count      mean       std       min       25%       50%       75%       max
0    4.0  0.341798  1.452760 -0.516745 -0.456267 -0.313535  0.484530  2.511008
1    4.0 -0.151615  0.680945 -0.692965 -0.483918 -0.378968 -0.046664  0.844442
2    4.0  0.186745  1.408807 -1.190361 -0.946510  0.257237  1.390493  1.422869
3    4.0  0.696535  0.850926 -0.134516  0.015622  0.703306  1.384219  1.514046
4    4.0  0.333963  0.693706 -0.269957 -0.083315  0.147917  0.565195  1.309977
```

and

```
   count      mean      std       min       25%       50%      75%       max
0    4.0  0.341798  1.45276 -0.516745 -0.456267 -0.313535  0.48453  2.511008
```

Respectively.

If you want to see all columns you can use `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)`

Comment: You are using transposition `df.T`. That is a known solution but my question specifically asked for a method that would avoid transposing the whole df.

Comment: I do use the transform but not on the original table, only on the describe table.  Also it makes it possible to work with only one column, which was the main reason why I did add this solution. I would like to leave the answer for people that need it to work on a single column.

Comment: Although this answer with a `df.describe().T` transformation may not exactly be what was asked for, I am glad you provided it still, @Thymen. I needed to display the output of the `df.describe()` function in a way that will fit my page width and that helped.