# Descriptive statistics along rows of text file using Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am reading a text file using Pandas in Python. I am using Python 2.7. The dataset in use in this question is related to a question that I had asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508642/importing-file-containing-text-and-numerical-data-using-python/52508700?noredirect=1#comment91957817_52508700). To be specific, the first two rows, and the first column of my data comprise of text information. The following is a snapshot of a truncated version of my dataset. [image]

The data file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vFYi27jDins8J8-lbjuUiFkgKcdRVs2h/view?usp=sharing). I am using the helpful answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508642/importing-file-containing-text-and-numerical-data-using-python/52508700?noredirect=1#comment91957817_52508700) to load the dataset (`df = pd.read_csv('dum.txt',sep='\t', header=[0,1], index_col=0)`).

I want to get descriptive statistics of my pandas dataframe along rows, instead of columns. I have tried using `df.describe()`, but it gives me descriptive statistics along columns. I had a look at the answers given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085081/pandas-df-describe-is-it-possible-to-do-it-by-row-without-transposing) question, but I get the following error when I use the answers suggested in that link.

```
TypeError: ('unbound method describe() must be called with DataFrame instance as first argument (got Series instance instead)', u'occurred at index foxq1')
```

How can I get descriptive statistics using Pandas for the numerical entries in every row for the dataset that I have? Thanks in advance.

---

Following a few comments, I am including the actual code that I am using, and the error message:

The **actual code** is this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dum.txt',sep='\t', header=[0,1], index_col=0)
df.apply(pd.DataFrame.describe, axis=1)
```

**Error message**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-0d7a5fde0f42> in <module>()
----> 1 df.apply(pd.DataFrame.describe, axis=1)
      2 #df.apply(pd.DataFrame.describe, axis=1)

/Users/LG/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4260                         f, axis,
   4261                         reduce=reduce,
-> 4262                         ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
   4263             else:
   4264                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

/Users/LG/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4356             try:
   4357                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4358                     results[i] = func(v)
   4359                     keys.append(v.name)
   4360             except Exception as e:

TypeError: ('unbound method describe() must be called with DataFrame instance as first argument (got Series instance instead)', u'occurred at index object1')
```

Comment: Please include the actual code that caused the problem and the complete error message.

Comment: @DYZ:  I included the code and the complete error message now. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: @DYZ: I am using Python 2.7. I am wondering if that might be a reason why I am getting errors.

Comment: Surely the code that you included (twice!) is not the actual code because it does not have the line that caused the error.

Comment: @DYZ: Sorry, corrected it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use numpy to obtain much of the statistics for rows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dum.txt',sep='\t', header=[0,1], index_col=0)
print df 

Type      T1   T2   T3   T4   T5   T6   T7
Tag     Tag1 Tag1 Tag1 Tag5 Tag5 Tag6 Tag6
object1  1.1  2.1  3.1  4.1  5.1  6.1  7.1
object2  1.2  2.2  3.2  4.2  5.2  6.2  7.2
object3  1.3  2.3  3.3  4.3  5.3  6.3  7.3
object4  1.4  2.4  3.4  4.4  5.4  6.4  7.4
object5  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5
object6  1.6  2.6  3.6  4.6  5.6  6.6  7.6
object7  1.7  2.7  3.7  4.7  5.7  6.7  7.7
object8  1.8  2.8  3.8  4.8  5.8  6.8  7.8

data = df.values
data_mean = np.mean(data, axis=1)
data_std = np.std(data, axis=1)
data_min = np.min(data, axis=1)
data_max = np.max(data, axis=1)

print data_mean 

[ 4.1  4.2  4.3  4.4  4.5  4.6  4.7  4.8]

print data_std

[ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]

print data_min

[ 1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8]

print data_max

[ 7.1  7.2  7.3  7.4  7.5  7.6  7.7  7.8]
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085081/pandas-df-describe-is-it-possible-to-do-it-by-row-without-transposing) you referenced, you can just use this code (in other words apply describe along the rows):

```
df.apply(pd.DataFrame.describe, axis=1)
```

And you get the following result:

```
         count  mean       std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
object1    5.0   3.1  1.581139  1.1  2.1  3.1  4.1  5.1
object2    5.0   3.2  1.581139  1.2  2.2  3.2  4.2  5.2
object3    5.0   3.3  1.581139  1.3  2.3  3.3  4.3  5.3
object4    5.0   3.4  1.581139  1.4  2.4  3.4  4.4  5.4
object5    5.0   3.5  1.581139  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5
object6    5.0   3.6  1.581139  1.6  2.6  3.6  4.6  5.6
object7    5.0   3.7  1.581139  1.7  2.7  3.7  4.7  5.7
object8    5.0   3.8  1.581139  1.8  2.8  3.8  4.8  5.8
```

Comment: I get the following error when I use the method that you described: `TypeError: ('unbound method describe() must be called with DataFrame instance as first argument (got Series instance instead)', u'occurred at index object1')`

Comment: Joe: Are you using Python 2.7?

Comment: Oh sorry, I am using Python 3.6. That might be the problem. Also what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Joe: I really appreciate your help, and am thankful.  =)  The version of pandas that I am using is this : ` u'0.22.0' `

Comment: I updated from 0.21.x a few months ago as a command was not working properly. I am now using 0.23.4. You can try updating pandas and see if that fixes the issue.